# Dynamic Query Builder for Asp.net This Code is Useful Or Not?

Tags: asp.net

I am using this code for dynamic query. Is this useful or not?

> This Code for Dynamic Query

I'm using this type code for query builder

This is for `Select` statement:

```
public static string SelectQuery(List<string> NoofColumns, string TableName, Dictionary<string, string> WhereCondition)
{
    string SqlQuery = string.Empty;

    if (NoofColumns.Count == 0)
    {
            return null; //Columns are not supplied
    }
    else
    {
            SqlQuery += "Select ";

            foreach (string key in NoofColumns)
            {
                SqlQuery += key + ", ";
            }

            SqlQuery = SqlQuery.Remove(SqlQuery.LastIndexOf(","));
            //SqlQuery = SqlQuery.Remove(SqlQuery.Length - 1);
            SqlQuery += " from " + TableName;
     }

     if (WhereCondition.Count == 0)
     {
         return SqlQuery;
     }
     else
     {
         SqlQuery += " where ";

         foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> key in WhereCondition)
         {
                if (key.Value != "")
                {
                    SqlQuery += key.Key + " = '" + key.Value + "'" + " and ";
                }
                else
                {
                    SqlQuery += key.Key + " and ";
                }
        }

        SqlQuery = SqlQuery.Remove(SqlQuery.LastIndexOf("and"));
        return SqlQuery;
    }
}
```

This is for `Delete` statement:

```
    public static string DeleteQuery(Dictionary<string, string> fields, string TableName, Dictionary<string, string> WhereCondition)
    {
        string SqlQuery = string.Empty;

        if (fields.Count == 0)
        {
            SqlQuery += "Delete from ";
            SqlQuery += TableName + " ";
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (WhereCondition.Count == 0)
        {
            return SqlQuery;
        }
        else
        {
            SqlQuery += " where ";
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> key in WhereCondition)
            {
                SqlQuery += key.Key + " = '" + key.Value + "'" + " and ";
            }
            SqlQuery = SqlQuery.Remove(SqlQuery.LastIndexOf("and"));
            return SqlQuery;
        }
    }

    **//----for Insert ----**

    Hashtable args = new Hashtable();
    string table;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs Insert object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="table">table name to insert to</param>
    public DataLogics(string table)
    {
        this.table = table;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds item to Insert object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">item name</param>
    /// <param name="val">item value</param>
    public void Add(string name, object val)
    {
        args.Add(name, val);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes item from Insert object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">item name</param>
    public void Remove(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            args.Remove(name);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw (new Exception("No such item"));
        }
    }
```

This for making query:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Test representation of the Insert object (SQL query)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>System.String</returns>
    public string ToString(string Operation, string wherecondition)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder();
            string query = "";

            IDictionaryEnumerator enumInterface = args.GetEnumerator();
            bool first = true;
            if (Operation == "Insert")
            {
                while (enumInterface.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (first) first = false;
                    else
                    {
                        s1.Append(", ");
                        s2.Append(", ");
                    }
                    s1.Append(enumInterface.Key.ToString());
                    if (enumInterface.Value is DateTime)
                    {
                        s2.Append("'" + enumInterface.Value + "'");
                    }
                    else if (enumInterface.Value is String)
                    {
                        s2.Append("'" + Convert.ToString(enumInterface.Value) + "'");
                    }
                    else if (enumInterface.Value is Double)
                    {
                        s2.Append(Convert.ToDouble(enumInterface.Value.ToString()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        s2.Append(enumInterface.Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            if (Operation == "Update")
            {
                while (enumInterface.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (first) first = false;
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    //s1.Append("=");
                    // s2.Append(",");

                    if (enumInterface.Value is DateTime)
                    {
                        //s2.Append("'" + enumInterface.Value + "'");
                        s1.Append(enumInterface.Key.ToString() + "=" + "'" + enumInterface.Value + "'" + ",");
                    }
                    //else if (enumInterface.Value is Int32)
                    //{
                    //    //s2.Append(enumInterface.Value.ToString());
                    //    s1.Append(enumInterface.Key.ToString() + "=" + enumInterface.Value.ToString() + ",");
                    //}
                    //else if (enumInterface.Value is Double)
                    //{
                    //    //s2.Append(Convert.ToDouble(enumInterface.Value.ToString()));
                    //    s1.Append(enumInterface.Key.ToString() + "=" + Convert.ToDouble(enumInterface.Value.ToString() + ","));
                    //}
                    else
                    {
                        //s2.Append("'" + Convert.ToString(enumInterface.Value) + "'");
                        s1.Append(enumInterface.Key.ToString() + "=" + "'" + Convert.ToString(enumInterface.Value) + "'" + ",");
                    }
                    query = "Update " + table + " Set " + s1;
                }
            }
            if (Operation == "Update")
            {
                query = query.Remove(query.LastIndexOf(","));
                query = query + " Where " + wherecondition;
            }

            if (Operation == "Insert")
            {
                query = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (" + s1 + ") VALUES (" + s2 + ");";
            }

            SqlConnection con = Create_Connection.Open_Connection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            int id = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            args.Clear();
            con.Close();
            string retu = "";

            if (id == 1)
            {
                retu = "1";
            }
            else if (id == -1)
            {
                retu = "-1";
            }
            return retu;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "0";
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets item into Insert object
    /// </summary>
    object this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            Debug.Assert(args.Contains(key), "Key not found");
            return args[key];
        }
        set { args[key] = value; }
    }
```

Comment: And where is the question???

Comment: `StringBuilder.AppendFormat` is your friend